# Can it be specified that an application install to the user's home screen?

Tags: installation, app-icons

When installing an apk I noticed that the application's icon tends to be placed in the last available slot in the last page of the application navigation window (i.e. not the *main* window). At least on the Samsung Galaxy S6, the new application does not necessarily to go the first slot, but is sent to the very end.

Is there a way to specify where the application will install? For example, can I specify that I would like the icon to go to the first slot of the *main* screen if a slot is available?

Forgive me if I am way off base with the Android parlance. By *main screen* I mean the one(s) immediately viewable by the user -- the one in which you would otherwise have to manually bring a icon into by virtue of long-presses of the icon via the app navigation window.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327173/how-can-i-add-my-applications-shortcut-to-the-homescreen-upon-app-installation) will do what I want, but the posted solution is such that the application itself does the shortcut creation, but such a method would fail on the first install.